# Connect to VPN Server from command line on headless system

Tags: debian, command-line-interface, cisco-vpn

Is there a (relatively) hassle free way to connect as a client to a VPN Server (which uses Cisco IPSec)? The client is a Debian headless system hence the connection needs to be established from the command line. The VPN Server uses a shared secret (besides Username and Passwort), but **no group name**. I think with a group name vpnc should work, but as far as I can tell it does not if no group name is provided.